# Error with setting location request description text

Tags: ios, swift, location, info.plist

I'm attempting to set the description text, when apple prompts the user to chose whether they give my app permission to use location services (explaining to the user why I need to utilize location services).

In my info.plist I've added the following.

[image]

However, when I open my app and request location services, the description is "Location when in use description" instead of "Random Text".

How do I correctly set the description text?

Thanks

(Edit) - Pictures of info.plist source code

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you show the corresponding XML snippet of the Info.plist? (Right click on Info.plist, Open As, Source Code)

Comment: Hey @lazarevzubov I added the XML snippet of the info.plist. Please refer to the line numbers to better understand both pictures.

Comment: What if you use this permission instead? `Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description`